# Como darle el formato DD/MM/YYYY a un campo tipo Date de una tabla en oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date

Tengo una consulta la cual obtiene algunos campos tipo Date

El resultado de esta consulta se descarga en un archivo .csv y lo que hace es que NO muestra los campos de fecha con formato DD/MM/YYYY, trate de convertirlos con `to_char` pero al mostrarlos en el excel salen todos con una misma fecha y otro año que nada que ver y al probar con `to_date` salen correctas las fechas pero en otro formato, algo como esto `Sat Jun 14 00:00:00 18`

```html
SELECT F.ID, F.NOMBRE, TO_DATE(F.FECHA_INI,'DD/MM/YYYY') FECHA_INI, TO_DATE(F.FECHA_REGISTRO,'DD/MM/YYYY') FECHA_REGISTRO, TO_DATE(F.FECHA.CARGA,'DD/MM/YYYY') FECHA CARGA, TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_UNO,'fm9990.00'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00')
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR  F.ID =?1)
AND F.FECHA_INI &gt;= TO_DATE(?2 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND F.FECHA_INI &lt;= TO_DATE(?3 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

porque sale ese formato y no el que puse de DD/MM/YYYY?

que me hace fata o esta mal?
Sera que es tema de como excel interpreta los datos?

Tengo el siguiente código que mando a llamar desde mi controller para generar el archivo .csv

```html
if(factList !=null) {
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=archivo.csv");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write("ID,NOMBRE,FECHA_INI, FECHA_REGISTRO");
    out.write("\n");
    for(String factu: factList){
        out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation()); 
        out.write("\n"); 
    } 
    out.flush(); 
    out.close(); 
}else{ 
    log.info("Esta vacio"); 
} 
}catch(ControlException e){ throw new ControlException("Error", e); 
} 
}
```

Comment: cual es el tipo de dato de esos campos

Comment: Son DATE, asi están en la BD

Comment: Probaste con select to_char(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')  from dual

Comment: Lo probé así   to_char(F.FECHA_INI,'DD/MM/YYYY') y tampoco

Comment: puedes ejecutar scripts a mano, para consultar la DB ?
En ese caso select to_char(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
Asi vemos como formatea la fecha actual

Comment: Me da a mi que el problema va a estar en como recuperas los datos desde java. Si lo que haces es recuperar un Date al convertirlo a String directamente te saldra ese formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dicen los compañeros, y suponiendo que los campos de fechas sean de tipo `DATE`, debería funcionar con `TO_CHAR(campo_fecha, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.

Si seguimos suponiendo que esos campos son de tipo `DATE`, `TO_DATE(F.FECHA_INI,'DD/MM/YYYY')` no funciona puesto que `TO_DATE()` sólo convierte campos de tipo `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, or `NVARCHAR2`.

La única manera que conozco de usar `TO_DATE()` con una fecha, sería usar sólo el primer parámetro de la función, dando como resultado la fecha tal cuál está en base de datos: por ejemplo, si tienes el campo `FECHA` en BBDD con valor `25/07/2018 10:28:00`, entonces `TO_DATE(FECHA)` daría como resultado `25/07/2018 10:28:00`.

Una forma fácil de convertir esos campos fecha al formato que quieres, sería dándoles formato en tu código java.

Para ello te creas una variable con el formato que quieres de tipo `SimpleDateFormat`, y luego le aplicas el formato a la fecha:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
...

String fecha = f.format(FECHA_INI);
```

En tu código, puedes aplicarlo sobre cada uno de los campos de fecha que cuando creas el String de las filas para exportar al `.csv`, y en la query coger las fechas sin formateo:

```
SELECT F.ID, F.NOMBRE, F.FECHA_INI, F.FECHA_REGISTRO, F.FECHA.CARGA, TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_UNO,'fm9990.00'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00')
FROM FACTURA F
....
```

Comment: ya probé to_date con un sólo parámetro y sale Fri Jun  28 00:00:00 CDT 2018, y respecto a lo que mencionas que lo haga desde el java, la primera línea del  out.write("ID,NOMBRE, n")  pone esos nombres en la cabecera del Excel y con la línea que está adentro del for  out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation()); lleno los campos del Excel, entonces ese formateo que mencionas si va donde lo comentaste o iría dentro del método toCSVRepresentation() que está adentro de mi entidad?

Comment: A lo que me refiero con `TO_DATE()` es que el código que has mostrado no puede funcionar con dos parámetros si el primero es una fecha. El `out.write()`, puedes decirme como creas `factList`y como asignas los valores?

Comment: He editado la respuesta @Root93

Comment: Gracias, me ayudó

Answer (score 0):

actualiza el nuevo campo `CODFAC` con la concatenación de `ORDENID` y `FECHAORDEN`

```
UPDATE ORDENES SET CODFAC = TO_CHAR(ORDENID) || TO_CHAR(FECHAORDEN, 'YYYYMMDD');
```